# C# set language of any control in a web page by a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, globalization, cultureinfo

i have a web form and i want to change its titles for each control with the language thats chosen by a dropdown.

but i couldnt do it. I messed with json and complicated things.

here what i tried:

controller

```
string newstr = db.Countries.Where(c => c.CountryTag.Contains(incoming)).Select(c => c.CountryTag).First().ToString();
System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(newstr, false);
Resources.Global.Culture = ci;
```

view

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function changeLang(chosen) {
        var lang = $("#Language").val();
        $.getJSON('@Url.Content("~/Home/Globalx/")', { incoming: lang }, function (data) {
            location.reload(false);
            $("#Language").options.selectedIndex = data;
        })
    }
</script>

<div>
    @Html.DropDownList("Language", (SelectList)ViewData["Language"], new { onchange = "changeLang(this)" })
</div>
<div>
     @Resources.Global.Wellcome
</div>
```

but it doesnt works. Im using resources as you can see in the code..

I just want to see the changed language on my page whenever i choose another language from my dropdown.

Like while using win forms `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = MyChosenCulture;` in a `DropDown_Change` event bla bla.. 
but in web version.

so how can i achive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process is actually the same as what you mention for WinForms, but you were looking at the wrong property (`CurrentCulture` is about formatting and parsing, it's `CurrentUICulture` that you need to make ResourceManager use a specific language version of your resources). So you can achieve your goal by replacing this line:

```
Resources.Global.Culture = ci;
```

With this one:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
```